# Form submission prevent default onsubmit() is not working in ajax success

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, forms, spring-mvc

In my java spring-mvc web-app I am calling a function in ajax success function on submit button's `submit()` event to submit a spring form on submit button click. There I need to avoid the default form submit. But it is not working? How can I prevent this deafault submit?

My javascript:

```
function contentPackge() {
  //...

  $.ajax({
        url: "..",
        data: {},
        type: "POST",
        success: function() {
          $("#btnAddNewPkg").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
            showloadingif();
            setTimeout(function() {
              $("#frmAddPkg").submit();
            }, 3000);
          });
          window.location.href += "#last";
          location.reload(true);
        },
```

JSP page button:

```
<form:button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnAddNewPkg" 
onsubmit="contentPackge();">Submit
</form:button>
```

Comment: can you remove ' type="submit" ' and try to invoke ajax on click event of that button?

Comment: You should use an unobtrusive event handler and call `preventDefault()` on the provided event - however you have much more serious problems, such as the nested form submission event handlers and calls. That's not going to work at all. Also reloading the page after making an AJAX request makes the use of AJAX pretty redundant.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you please refine any code segment for me if  there is a better way to do so?

Comment: @Valath It s not working

Comment: Anybody can help with this please??

Comment: Multiple traditional form submit in a single page will never happen. Please think of a different implementation to achieve what you need.